# IF ELSE STATEMENT in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure, but I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near ';'

I think there is something wrong with the `IF Else` statements.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE setSystemStaff
    @SYSTEMNAME nvarchar(50),
    @STAFFNAME nvarchar(50),
    @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH t1 (SYSTEMID) AS 
    (
        SELECT SYSTEMID 
        FROM SYSTEM 
        WHERE SYSTEMNAME = @SYSTEMNAME
    ), t2 (STAFFID) AS 
    (
        SELECT STAFFID 
        FROM STAFF 
        WHERE STAFFNAME = @STAFFNAME
    );

    IF @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE = 'Owner'
        INSERT INTO SYSTEMSTAFF ([SYSTEMID], [SYSTEMSTAFFOWNER])    
            SELECT t1.SYSTEMID, t2.STAFFID 
            FROM t1, t2
    ELSE IF @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE = 'Specialist'
        INSERT INTO SYSTEMSTAFF ([SYSTEMID], [SYSTEMSTAFSPECIALIST])    
            SELECT t1.SYSTEMID, t2.STAFFID 
            FROM t1,t2  
    ELSE 
        RETURN  
END
GO
```

Comment: You have 2 CTEs (t1 and t2), but you don't have a query using those afterwards. You must have one and it cannot be an IF statement, it has to be a query (see documentation for details and scope of CTEs).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Re-write the Procedure Using Case Statements, without using the `IF..ELSE`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE setSystemStaff
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@SYSTEMNAME nvarchar(50),
@STAFFNAME nvarchar(50),
@SYSTEMSTAFFROLE nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here
WITH t1 
(
    SYSTEMID
) 
AS 
(
    SELECT 
        SYSTEMID  
        FROM SYSTEM 
            WHERE SYSTEMNAME = @SYSTEMNAME
),
t2
(
    STAFFID
) 
AS 
(
    SELECT 
        STAFFID 
        FROM STAFF 
            WHERE STAFFNAME = @STAFFNAME
);
INSERT INTO SYSTEMSTAFF
(
    [SYSTEMID],
    [SYSTEMSTAFFOWNER],
    [SYSTEMSTAFSPECIALIST]
)
SELECT
    SYSTEMID = t1.SYSTEMID,
    SYSTEMSTAFFOWNER = CASE WHEN @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE = 'Owner'
                                THEN t2.STAFFID END,
    SYSTEMSTAFSPECIALIST = CASE WHEN @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE = 'Specialist'
                                THEN t2.STAFFID END
    FROM T1,T2

END
GO
```

And you can Also Simplyfy the Procedure Like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE setSystemStaff
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@SYSTEMNAME nvarchar(50),
@STAFFNAME nvarchar(50),
@SYSTEMSTAFFROLE nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here

INSERT INTO SYSTEMSTAFF
(
    [SYSTEMID],
    [SYSTEMSTAFFOWNER],
    [SYSTEMSTAFSPECIALIST]
)
SELECT
    SYSTEMID = t1.SYSTEMID,
    SYSTEMSTAFFOWNER = CASE WHEN @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE = 'Owner'
                                THEN t2.STAFFID END,
    SYSTEMSTAFSPECIALIST = CASE WHEN @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE = 'Specialist'
                                THEN t2.STAFFID END
    FROM SYSTEM T1
        INNER JOIN STAFF T2
            ON T1.SYSTEMNAME = @SYSTEMNAME
                AND T2.STAFFNAME = @STAFFNAME

END
GO
```

Comment: I would recommend always putting `... ELSE NULL ` before END at the end of your CASE statements to make the default explicitly visible.  Beware your code would override any '...DEFAULT..' constraints that would apply to the omitted columns per the INSERT code given in the question.

Comment: I like the second solution, as I just browsed thru the answers to look for the solution I had in mind. I wonder how nobody came up with a `CROSS JOIN` ;)

Comment: Thanks alot! I followed the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing 'then' keyword.
You should put this condition like

IF   then
--Statement (Insert /update/delete as required) 
elsif   then
--Statement (Insert /update/delete as required)

end if;

--Above syntax used in SQL only

Comment: I think you are confusing VB syntax and SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE setSystemStaff
(
    @SYSTEMNAME nvarchar(50),
    @STAFFNAME nvarchar(50),
    @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE = 'Owner'
    BEGIN
        WITH t1 AS 
        (
            SELECT SYSTEMID  FROM SYSTEM WHERE SYSTEMNAME = @SYSTEMNAME
        )
        ,t2 AS 
        (
            SELECT STAFFID FROM STAFF WHERE STAFFNAME = @STAFFNAME
        )
        INSERT INTO SYSTEMSTAFF ([SYSTEMID],[SYSTEMSTAFFOWNER]) 
        SELECT t1.SYSTEMID, t2.STAFFID FROM t1,t2
    END
    ELSE IF @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE = 'Specialist'
    BEGIN
        WITH t1 AS 
        (
            SELECT SYSTEMID  FROM SYSTEM WHERE SYSTEMNAME = @SYSTEMNAME
        )
        ,t2 AS 
        (
            SELECT STAFFID FROM STAFF WHERE STAFFNAME = @STAFFNAME
        )
        INSERT INTO SYSTEMSTAFF ([SYSTEMID],[SYSTEMSTAFSPECIALIST]) 
        SELECT t1.SYSTEMID, t2.STAFFID FROM t1,t2  
    END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: pass to temporary table.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE setSystemStaff
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @SYSTEMNAME NVARCHAR(50) ,
        @STAFFNAME NVARCHAR(50) ,
        @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE NVARCHAR(50)
    AS
        BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here

            WITH    t1
                      AS ( SELECT   SYSTEMID
                           FROM     SYSTEM
                           WHERE    SYSTEMNAME = @SYSTEMNAME
                         ),
                    T2
                      AS ( SELECT   STAFFID
                           FROM     STAFF
                           WHERE    STAFFNAME = @STAFFNAME
                         ),
                    T3
                      AS ( SELECT   t1.SYSTEMID ,
                                    t2.STAFFID
                           FROM     t1 ,
                                    t2
                         )
                SELECT  *
                INTO    #temptbl
                FROM    t3


            IF @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE = 'Owner'
                BEGIN
                    INSERT  INTO SYSTEMSTAFF
                            ( [SYSTEMID] ,
                              [SYSTEMSTAFFOWNER]
                            )
                            SELECT  SYSTEMID ,
                                    STAFFID
                            FROM    #temptbl
                END 
            ELSE
                IF @SYSTEMSTAFFROLE = 'Specialist'
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT  INTO SYSTEMSTAFF
                                ( [SYSTEMID] ,
                                  [SYSTEMSTAFSPECIALIST]
                                )
                                SELECT  SYSTEMID ,
                                        STAFFID
                                FROM    #temptbl
                    END

            RETURN

        END
    GO
```